# Savings values to file form field on form submission - theme-settings.php

Tags: 8, forms

I'm trying to build a custom file upload field in my `theme-settings.php` file, but I can't seem to get the uploaded file to persist after the form is submitted. Setting the default value as it is set below causes an error 500 and the theme settings page won't load at all. With it commented out, I'm able to upload a file I see the uploaded files in my files directory but it doesn't show up in the form as a currently set value - am I missing something here?

Current code below.

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeSettings;
use Drupal\system\Form\ThemeSettingsForm;
use Drupal\Core\Form;

function strata_form_system_theme_settings_alter(array &$form, Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $form['strata_settings']['hero'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Hero Image'),
        '#type' => 'managed_file',
        '#description' => t('A hero image for the homepage'),
        //'#default_value' => theme_get_setting('hero'),
        '#required' => FALSE,
        '#upload_validators' => array(
            'file_validate_extensions' => array("png jpg jpeg gif"),
        ),
    );
}
```